# How to encapsulate a class that is only being used inside another class?

Tags: c++, oop, inner-classes, encapsulation

Shown below is a rough structure of the program.

```
class Room 
{
private:
    Node* content;
public:
    void someRoomMethod();
};

void Room::someRoomMethod() {}


class Node
{
private:
    Node* nextNode;
    std::variant<int, float> data;
public:
    void someNodeMethod();
};

void Node::someNodeMethod() {}
```

As I mentioned in the title `Node` is not being used anywhere other than inside `Room`. I've tried to encapsulate Node by making it a nested class but it didn't work.

```
// Room.hh

class Room 
{
private:
    Room::Node* content; // ERROR: no type named "Node" in "Room" -- GCC

public:
    void roomMethod();

    class Node()
    {
    private:
        Node* nextNode;
        std::variant<int, float> data;
    public:
        void someNodeMethod();
    }
};

// Room.cpp
void Room::someRoomMethod() {} // sees Room in Room.hh

// Node.cpp
void Room::Node::someNodeMethod() {} // sees Node in Room.hh
```

Questions:

1. How exactly should I encapsulate `Node` so that I could create a variable of type `Node` inside `Room` and so that `Node` couldn't be used anywhere except inside `Room`. Please note that I will need a linked list of type `Node` inside each instance `Room`.
2. Should methods of `Node` be moved to external .cpp file like it is now? Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declarations of a nested class are parsed lexically (the same as at file scope). Simply move the usage of `Node` after the definition:

```
class Room 
{  
  private:

    class Node
    {
      // ...
    };
  
    Room::Node* content; // fine, Node is defined already

  public:
     // ...
};
```

Since `Node` is only used inside `Room` it should be `private`.

---

Yes, you should move the definitions of `Node` methods to a `.cpp` file to separate implementation and interface. This is the same as for regular class methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have to at least declare a type before you can use it:

```
class Room 
{


public:
    void roomMethod();

    class Node                          // no () 
    {
    private:
        Node* nextNode;
        std::variant<int, float> data;
    public:
        void someNodeMethod();
    };                                  // missing ;
private: 
    Node* content;

};
```